# Wagtail 4.1, 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to integrate wagtail into an existing django project, but I am getting the above error when I add a child page.

In my settings I have followed the instructions so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'home',
    'news',
    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail',
    'modelcluster',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django_permissions_policy.PermissionsPolicyMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]
```

my project urls:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import reverse
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
    path('cms/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path('documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path('news/', include(wagtail_urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my news urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import news_article_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('news/<int:pk>/', news_article_detail, name='news_article_detail'),
]
```

in my news view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import NewsArticlePage
#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

def news_article_detail(request, pk):
    news_article = NewsArticlePage.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'news/news_page.html', {'news_article': news_article})
```

and my model:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField

class NewsArticlePage(Page):
    article_body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('article_body'),
    ]
    
    template = "news/news_page.html"
```

and in my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
{{ page.article_body|richtext }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have also added the root page, made sure that the url's are pointing to the correct place, made migrations & migrated but still I get the same error. So when I go to localhost/cms in the backend I have a page set up, when I go to add a child page I get the error, I tried the python manage.py fixtree but I still get the error, here is the stack trace:

nvironment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:7000/cms/pages/add/news/newsarticlepage/2/

```
Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.11.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'accounts',
 'compressor',
 'corsheaders',
 'home',
 'news',
 'taggit',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'sass_processor',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail',
 'modelcluster']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django_permissions_policy.PermissionsPolicyMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\urls\__init__.py", line 170, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\auth.py", line 182, in decorated_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\pages\create.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\pages\create.py", line 132, in post
    return self.form_valid(self.form)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\pages\create.py", line 148, in form_valid
    return self.save_action()
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\wagtail\admin\views\pages\create.py", line 170, in save_action
    self.parent_page.add_child(instance=self.page)
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 1089, in add_child
    return MP_AddChildHandler(self, **kwargs).process()
  File "C:\Users\sesa301575\sites\Django.Azure\venv\Lib\site-packages\treebeard\mp_tree.py", line 383, in process
    newobj.path = self.node.get_last_child()._inc_path()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cms/pages/add/news/newsarticlepage/2/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'
```

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail what you are doing when you get that error message? And include the actual stack trace?

Comment: Also, creating an explicit view for your wagtail pages, is unusual. Generally one uses Wagtail's page serving mechanism which in your case would mean the pages you create will be publicly available at example.com/news/<page_slug>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'` usually indicates that the internal fields (`path`, `depth`, `numchild`) defined by the [django-treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/) library for keeping track of child counts in the page tree have become inconsistent. It's unclear what might have caused that here, but running `./manage.py fixtree` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks gasman, I tried your suggestion but still get the same error, I have edited my question with stack trace

Comment: As you suggested, there was confusion in my urls as you suggested, i had both path('news/', include('news.urls')), & path('news/', include(wagtail_urls)), many thanks @gasman

Comment: On my projects I usually need to run `./manage.py fixtree --full` to resolve issues. If that still isn't working, there is a `find_problems` method on MP_Node but there isn't a manage command to access it; you would need to dive around in the django shell to use it.

Comment: comments in this issue explain roughly why it happens https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/7434 ...my case was exactly as described there - previous attempt to save draft had failed due to bug on my site, after fixing that I was getting this error and `./manage.py fixtree` resolved it

Comment: Adding --full was required to fix my problem. Thank you @cnk